# writing data into firebase through an android application

Tags: android, firebase

I am a newbie with firebase and trying to use this as the backend for an android app to store data. The format of the data is a key,value pair.

This is the code that I am using to store the data :

```
Map<Integer, PersonData> map = new HashMap<Integer, PersonData>();
map.put(PersonData.getID(), new PersonData("abcd", 12345));
Firebase ref = new Firebase(url).push();
ref.setValue(map);
```

Due to the push reference being used the data is getting stored  like this :

```
-J5upSABqTLJ1Wfu-jFq  
 12345
   id: 12345
   name: abcd
```

Where-as I want the data to be store like this :

```
12345
   id: 12345
   name: abcd
```

I am not entirely sure if the code sample above is the right way to store data. Since I want to be able to update the existing data at a later point in time . Any suggestions ?

EDIT 1: I am thinking I need to use push so that I don't over-write the existing data in the firebase repo. 
I have just tried to get the data back using the getValue() method and I can only fetch data  which is in MAP

EDIT 2: without using a push() method with my reference I can see that the any previous data is getting overwritten and only the latest information is available. I am wondering if they is a better way to obtain the reference and still maintain the previous information

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So it looks like you have your own system of unique ids, in which case you shouldn't need to use the `.push` method (that is just a helper to get a unique ref for new data). So instead of push you should be able to do:

```
Map<Integer, PersonData> map = new HashMap<Integer, PersonData>();
map.put(PersonData.getID(), new PersonData("abcd", 12345));
Firebase ref = new Firebase(url).child("12345");
ref.setValue(map);
```

Assuming your id is `"12345"` and `url` is pointing at the location where you want to store all of your `persons`.

To update the data without overwriting, your `ref` would be:

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase(url).child("12345");
```

And instead of using `.setValue` you would want to use `ref.updateChildren(updates)`. You can see how to structure the `updates` from the example in the [docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/writing-data.html):

```
Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<String, Object>();
updates.put("first", "Fred");
updates.put("last", "Swanson");
nameRef.updateChildren(updates);
```