# writing data into firebase using an iphone app

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19375035/writing-data-into-firebase-through-an-android-application) was the question I had asked in order to write data into firebase through an android app, I want to represent the information in the same way in an iphone app.

I am using a dictionary to represent the key-value pairs.

```
 f = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"https://ums-ios.firebaseio.com/"];
   NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"latitude",[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:latitude] stringValue],
                           @"longitude",[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:longitude] stringValue],
                           @"timestamp",[[NSNumber numberWithDouble:timeStamp] stringValue],
                            nil];
Firebase* tempRef = [f childByAppendingPath:@"mobileNum"]; 
[tempRef setValue:dictionary];
```

I am getting an exception when I try to run this. But when I replace the `NSDictionary`  with `NSArray` my data is getting mapped to `array indices`, which is not what I would require.

any suggestions ?

Comment: What's the exception?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's unrelated, butyour dictionary is backwards.  I also find it terribly annoying, and I feel like I always have to double check, but values come before keys for iOS

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:latitude] stringValue], @"latitude",
                        [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:longitude] stringValue], @"longitude",
                        [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:timeStamp] stringValue], @"timestamp",
                        nil];
```

The full code would be this

```
float latitude = 30.472;
float longitude = 42.467;
double timeStamp = NSTimeIntervalSince1970;
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:latitude] stringValue], @"latitude",
                            [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:longitude] stringValue], @"longitude",
                            [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:timeStamp] stringValue], @"timestamp",
                            nil];

Firebase * f = [[Firebase alloc]initWithUrl:@"https://ums-ios.firebaseio.com/"];
Firebase* tempRef = [f childByAppendingPath:@"mobileNum"];
[tempRef setValue:dictionary];
```

This will create the following URL scheme (added .json so you can see easy)

https://ums-ios.firebaseio.com/mobileNum/.json = the dictionary

https://ums-ios.firebaseio.com/mobileNum/latitude/.json = value for latitude

https://ums-ios.firebaseio.com/mobileNum/longitude/.json = value for longitude

https://ums-ios.firebaseio.com/mobileNum/timestamp/.json = value for timestamp

A note on security,

I just saved this data to your firebase, make sure you update security before releasing!